# LDAPs Simple Authentication on Tomcat 9

Tags: ldap, tomcat, authentication

I have a web application running on Tomcat 9 and using LDAPS for user Authentication. When I connect via LDAP (non-secure) the authentication is successful but when I switch to LDAPS (Secure) I get "PenLdapLookupModule: Error authenticating during a lookup. Please check the username and password used to log into LDAP" error. Yet am using same username and password unencrypted within the application.

***Tomcat configuration (Server.xml)***

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
    debug="99"
    connectionURL="ldaps://ldapservername:636"
    authentication="simple"
    connectionName="<username>"
    connectionPassword="<password>"
    userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    userBase="dc=com"
    userSubtree="true"
    userRoleName="memberOf"
    roleBase="ou=Global Security Groups,ou=Security Groups,ou=Domain Groups,dc=directory,dc=com"
    roleSearch="(member={0})"
    roleSubtree="true"
    roleName="cn"
/>
```

***Application LDAP configs***

```
setconfig ldap.ssl.trustStore.type "JKS"
setconfig ldap.ssl.trustStore.location "ldapsKeystorename.jks"
setconfig ldap.ssl.trustStore.password "<Keystorepassword>"
```

***Logs***

```
ERROR [LookupRefresh] (PenLdapLookupModule) - PenLdapLookupModule: Error authenticating during a lookup.
Please check the username and password used to log into LDAP.
If encryption is enabled you may need to reset the password (to its plain text value) if the application software has changed.

com.paisley.core.FaultException: FAULT -- DETAILS BELOW

Error authenticating during a lookup. Please check the username and
password used to log into LDAP. If encryption is enabled you may need to
reset the password (to its plain text value) if the application software has
changed.
Thread name:                            LookupRefresh - 0x2b
Occurred on/at:                         4/8/21 12:25:01 PM SAST
Session Client ID:                      
Group Name:                             
Client ID:                              com.paisley.foundation.client.ClientID@8e812e86-client001
Module Name:                            PenLdapLookupModule

        at com.paisley.rnj.security.lookup.PenLdapLookupModule.lookup(PenLdapLookupModule.java:162)
        at com.paisley.rnj.security.service.LookupServiceBean.performLookup(LookupServiceBean.java:720)
        at com.paisley.rnj.security.service.LookupServiceBean.refresh(LookupServiceBean.java:471)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at com.paisley.foundation.reflect.ReflectorToolkit.callMethod(ReflectorToolkit.java:1345)
        at com.paisley.foundation.database.transaction.ServiceTransactionInjector.callRealServiceMethod(ServiceTransactionInjector.java:336)
        at com.paisley.foundation.database.transaction.ServiceTransactionInjector.invoke(ServiceTransactionInjector.java:178)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.refresh(Unknown Source)
        at com.paisley.rnj.security.lookup.work.LookupInitializeWork.execute(LookupInitializeWork.java:86)
        at com.paisley.rnj.security.lookup.thread.LookupRefreshBackgroundTask.execute(LookupRefreshBackgroundTask.java:94)
        at com.paisley.foundation.background.BackgroundThread.run(BackgroundThread.java:141)
```

Comment: please show the configuration used, and the relevant logs

Comment: @natxoasenjo, Details added as requested

Comment: could you use the fqdn in the ldap uri instead of the short name?

Comment: and verify obviously that your bind username/password are correct. I think the userBase should also be dc=directory,dc=com instead of dc=com

Comment: @natxoasenjo. Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I confirmed the credentials are all good. This config works if connecting to LDAP, But fails when connecting to LDAPs. The only difference is that with LDAPs, you connect to the secure port. So essentially this should work as is

Comment: @Ismail: does the LDAP server use a _trusted_ certificate (trusted by Java)? The error might be due to a SSL handshake failure.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, Yes correct, it does use a trusted certificate.

Comment: you need to debug the realm authentication in tomcat. Could you try the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333709/how-to-debug-tomcat-ldap-realm-queries ?

Comment: Hello guys. Apologies I stopped working on this piece for a while. Started again this week, 
Problem cause: The latest Java Runtime Environment has SSLv3 disabled by default. So my application was making use of SSLv3, which is why it was failing to authenticate on LDAPS. Even following the recommended steps below didn't work

Go to Java installation folder.
Open {JRE_HOME}\lib\security\java.security -file in text editor.
Go to the last line.
Delete or comment out the following line "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3".
Restart the MC service or reboot the server.

Comment: I had to switch to using the Amazon Corretto 8 JDK, this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies I stopped working on this piece for a while. Started again this week

**Problem cause**: The latest Java Runtime Environment has SSLv3 disabled by default. So my application was making use of SSLv3, which is why it was failing to authenticate on LDAPS. Following the recommended steps below didn't work either

- Open {JRE_HOME}\lib\security\java.security -file in text editor.
- Delete or comment out the following line
  "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3"

**Solution**: I had to switch to using the Amazon Corretto 8 JDK, this resolved the problem. I also had to remove the SSLv3 from the "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" in the java.security file.